# Rebooting takes too long after installing Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: boot

I installed Ubuntu 14.10, also installed Additional Drivers and so on, I followed carefully all these procedures one-by-one from  http://howtoubuntu.org/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-14-10-utopic-unicorn

But if I Restart my PC, it can't reboot correctly. Sometimes, you can only see it in blank screen, and too much time to load.. it's like I'm waiting for nothing.

I really don't know the exact cause of this problem (if graphics driver issue or else).

I'm using:

- APU: amd a6 3.6G w/ radeon hd 7540d
- RAM: 4GB

Answer (score 0):

First you have to identify the cause, so a good place to start would be the log files (i know, not so cute:) , but look at /var/log/boot.log  first

Then you could install bootchart (sudo apt-get install bootchart) to find where it waits and for how long.
- after installing bootchart you have to reboot.

The information you posted is a little 'generic' and hard for anyone to give an exact solution (if any).